# Express cannot find module "rmp-api"

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to use an api from github that takes rate my professor ratings and the instructions were fairly clear. https://github.com/shafi-dayatar/rmp-api

```
npm install rmp-api --save
```

which worked but once I require it

```
var rmp = require('rmp-api');
```

It gives me the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'rmp-api'
```

I've tried rebuilding the app, reinstalling all the dependencies and still nothing. Is there something I might be missing from the installation?

Comment: can you please update your question with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rmp-api` package is no longer hosted in NPM. At this time, if you visit [the npm page for rmp-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rmp-api), you will see the following description:

> This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it.

It appears this happened 9 months ago, and based on the last commit being in August of 2016, I'd guess this package has been abandoned. If you want to use it, you can install it using the githubname/reponame syntax (see [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for more details):

```
npm install --save shafi-dayatar/rmp-api
```

Comment: Even on that, when you clone the github (https://github.com/shafi-dayatar/rmp-api) and you `npm install` on it, it runs for me successfully without any error. That's why I feel he needs to update his code.

Comment: Would I place the cloned file into my node_modules folder? By doing this, will my original var rmp = require('rmp-api'); work?

Comment: No need to clone the repo. npm will install it in `node_modules` just like a package from official npm land. Please review the linked documentation.